# how to clone raspbian OS with all files and settings

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am finishing a project in raspberry pi 1 b+, and I would like to clone your raspbian operating system, with all the configurations, installations and files, that you now have installed, in order to record this image in another memory, as a backup in case of that the memory that has rpi fails,
how could i do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

- Power off your Raspberry Pi.
- Remove the SD card and put it in a PC running Linux or a Mac.
- Use `dd` to read the entire SD card into a file (disk image) on that PC. This may take a few minutes, depending on the capacity/speed of your SD card and the speed of your PC.

The command will look something like:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/XXXXX bs=65536 > RaspberryPiImage.bin
```

where XXXXX is whatever is the furthest from `a` in the list `sda`, `sdb`, `sdc` through `sdz`.

Check the size of the file `RaspberryPiImage.bin` corresponds to the full capacity of your SD card. So if your SD card is 16GB, you should see close to 16GB if you run:

```
ls -lh RaspberryPiImage.bin
```

You'll probably want to compress the image as it will almost certainly be a) large and b) readily compressible.

You could use:

```
gzip RaspberryPiImage.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing and found hundreds of suggests how to write an image file or copy it with windows but it doing just on the Raspberry nobody had an answer. Finally I found a perfect solution:

At https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone you find a script rpi-clone, download it to you raspberry, connect an USB SDCard Reader and execute `rpi-clone sda`.